# Lit-element | Unable to load scss into lit-element

Tags: webpack, sass, lit-element, lit-html

I'm on Mac, latest chrome using webpack 4 with the current webpack scss/css loaders (this is the before state of the required scss lit-element loaders etc...):

use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", 'postcss-loader', "sass-loader"]

**I'm unable to successfully load scss into my lit-element component.**

I have used the following examples and have failed:

https://github.com/drdreo/lit-scss-loader,

https://github.com/clicksolutions/lit-element-scss-loader,

https://blog.webf.zone/on-styling-web-components-b74b8c70c492

All of the above have failed.

Is there a way you can successfully load a scss file into a lit-element component at this stage as doing the inline way is very messy and I'm repeating my self a lot:

```
static get styles () {
return css`
.magic-class-name {
    margin: 0;
}
.magic-class-name .magic-class-name2 .magic-class-name3 {
    margin: 0;
}  `
etc...
```

Comment: Can you provide a more comprehensive extract of the webpack configs you have tried? Some more details about the failures would be helpful as well

Comment: @Umbo Yup sure. Here is an example of the webpack css/sccs/sass loaders.. 
`{
        test: /\.css|\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'lit-scss-loader',
          options: {
            minify: true, // defaults to false
          },
        }, 'extract-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },`

And the result is the web component does not render on page load and console does not have any errors at all which isn't helpful. 

So really just wondering if anyone has had success implementing scss and lit-element.

Comment: Ok, and how are you importing the styles in your component? (BTW if you want you can edit the question and put the code there for more clarity)

Comment: @Umbo hey ya. This is exactly what I'm doing here: [https://github.com/drdreo/lit-scss-loader/blob/b01a5f3e63470ab4f231013b9fe9e9572d00e285/test-app/src/lit-test-component/lit-test-component.js

Comment: And still fails on me. I see my rendered web component but nothing inside it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on without more info. Maybe if you could create a repo to reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem aswell and found my way around it in a 'hacky' way!

What i started doing was directly inject my scss into my lit-element as a string and 'parse' it using unsafeCSS!

You'll need installed "to-string-loader":

```
yarn add to-string-loader -D
npm install to-string-loader --save-dev
```

My webpack config (relevant part):

```
{
    test: /\.(s?)css$/,
    use: [
      // to inject the result into the DOM as a style block
      { loader: "to-string-loader" }, 
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
      },
      {
       // to convert SASS to CSS
        loader: "sass-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Also don't forget to add scss/css to your extensions:

```
...
extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".scss", "css"],
...
```

With this Webpack will transpile your SCSS into CSS and insert its 'content' wherever it's required as a string!

in my classes I add the following to "static get styles()":

```
import {..., unsafeCSS, css } from "lit-element";

class WebComponent extends LitElement {
    static get styles() {
        return css`
          ${unsafeCSS(require("./path/to/your/styles.scss"))}
        `;
    }
}
```

Even if it's a bit hacky I still get the full intelissense of the IDE in my .scss styles!
And since there's no 'user input' in my scss file I'm not worrying too much about XSS either, even when using unsafeCSS().

Might not be the best but it's what I've done to make it work for now!

Good luck, I will watch this topic for better/improved answers aswell!

Comment: Did not work for me, it says `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css-loader' in ....`

Answer (score 0):

#### Using SCSS With Lit and Webpack

###### Installing Dependencies

First, you are going to need the following dependencies. Install them if they aren't already a part of your project.

```
npm install sass-loader@latest --save-dev
npm install lit-css-loader@latest --save-dev
```

The two commands above will install the packages and save then in your `package.json`.

###### Update Your `webpack.config.js` File

After installing the above dependencies, you'll need to update your `webpack.config.js` file with the following:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "lit-css-loader"
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sassOptions: {
                                    outputStyle: "compressed"
                                },
                            },
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Note that this is *not* the entire webpack config and the external parts are just to indicated where the rules object you are going to add goes. Only the object inside the `rules` array is what you are adding here.

It is extremely important that the loaders in the `use` array stay in the order they are in. Always have `lit-css-loader` first and `sass-loader` second.

###### Importing Your Stylesheet

In the file you are creating your stylesheet in (typically the lit component file, but some projects use external files to load stylesheets) you can now import your stylesheet with the following line of code:

`import stylesheet from "./toggle.stylesheet.scss";`

Just put it at the top of the file with the rest of your imports.

Inside the class definition you can now use the following line to define the styles for your component using the loaded SCSS file:

```
static styles = css`${stylesheet}`;
```

Note that we do *not* need to use `unsafeCSS` here because the `lit-css-loader` package handled converting our imported SCSS file to a `CSSResult` object as required by the `css` function. This keeps your application nice and secure.

###### TypeScript Accommodations

Here's what to do if you're using TypeScript and it's giving you you the following error:

`Cannot find module './*mystylesheet*.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.`

In the root folder of your project create a file called `global.d.ts`. This is going to serve as a typings file to define modules for your project. If you already have a `*.d.ts` file in your root or a `typings` folder with one or several of these files in it, you can either make a new file beside it, or update the existing file with the following:

`declare module '*.scss';`

Once you have created the file, open up your `tsconfig.json` file and look for the includes` array. You'll want to add a reference to your file here if there isn't already a glob reference that would include it.

Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
"include": [
    "global.d.ts"
]
```

Now that all of your configuration is done, make sure you restart any running processes before trying your luck. If your IDE is still throwing errors but everything is compiling OK you may need to restart your IDE for it to pick up on the changes to your `tsconfig.json` file.